# In Angular (9+), is there a way for each instance of a shared component to maintain its own, unique state?

Tags: angular, components, state

I've created an Angular component for a dynamic tree-like design.

The idea would be that you could add/update/remove nodes (which are nothing more than an instance of the component).

The reusable component is just a very vanilla, standard component with a ts/class file, an html file, and an scss file. The view is dirt simple - few form elements (couple of input boxes and a dropdown/select).

I'm using **two-way binding** to bind the HTLM elements to the class variables. However, it seems that the state of these variables is shared with ALL instances. I do not want this.

I need each instance of a component to have its OWN state.
As you can imagine, shared state presents a huge problem.

I don't want changes in node A updating every other node, for example.

How can I ensure each instance of a reusable component has its own state?

Comment: That's exactly how Angular would work. If each component is given an Input and Output, it will be it's out state data. Unless you are binding to a service. In which case the service will generally be a singleton. So perhaps code to show what you are doing is required here.

Comment: If you're passing as `@Input` one variable to your component remember pass two **different** variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is what Angular would do by default. So I assume there is something else going on that you aren't sharing.

A full demo is at the bottom, but to break it down:

If I have a template, creating a list of components:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, LittleviewComponent],
  template: `
    <div *ngFor="let n of myNumbers">
    <app-littleview  [displayNumber]="n"></app-littleview>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';

  myNumbers = [1,45,8,12, 99];
}
```

If the @Input is just a plain number:

```
@Input() displayNumber: number = 0;
```

Then each instance of the component will have it's own data.

[image]

If the data is from a service, it's going to behave differently.

[image]

```
constructor(public numberService: SharedNumberServiceService) { }
sharedNumber = this.numberService.numberObservable;
```

Generally, services are singletons. But there are various ways to change that. In 14+ standalone components, you can use the providers.

When using non-standalone (@ngModule) you can change the providedIn property of the @Injectable:

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
```

becomes

```
@Injectable()
```

And if you want to see the code in action:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8eid8f?file=src/littleview/littleview.component.html

Comment: Thanks. That’s what I thought. I went back to my code and checked. I had inadvertently given each input an id, so that same id was shared for every instance. This was making the value shared across instances

Answer (score 0):

Sure your problem is that you have not two variables else only one. This happens, e.g. when you equal two variable to the same object, e.g.

```
obj={id:'',name:''}
var1=this.obj;
var2=this.obj;

var1.id=1
console.log(var1) //{id:1,name:''}
console.log(var2) //{id:1,name:''}
```

You solve, making a "copy". You can use spread operator

```
obj={id:'',name:''}
var1={...this.obj};
var2={...this.obj};

var1.id=1
console.log(var1) //{id:1,name:''}
console.log(var2) //{id:'',name:''}
```

Equal happens when you pass an array of values